Command not found error in executing shell script on windows
I am executing below shell script in Git Bash in Windows, and getting an error saying command not found
$ sh scripts/Test.sh
File exists. Attempting to read...
sh: __git_ps1: command not found

Script:
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the file exists
if [ -f "data/dealers.txt" ]; then
    echo "File exists. Attempting to read..."
    
    # Read the file line by line
    while IFS=',' read -r dealer; do
        # Trim leading/trailing spaces (if necessary)
        dealer=$(echo "$dealer" | xargs)
        echo "Dealer: $dealer"
    done < data/dealers.txt
else
    echo "File does not exist or cannot be accessed."
fi

File contents are like: 0001,0002,0003.....
Edit: I ran the below command and error went away. $ curl -L https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh > ~/.bash_git But still cannot read the contents of the file.
$ sh scripts/Test.sh
File exists. Attempting to read...


The problem has to do with $PS1. Post output of printf "%s\n" "$PS1"

@Philippe $ printf "%s\n" "$PS1"
\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]__git_ps1\[\033[0m\]\n$

There's something very, very wrong if a noninteractive shell interpreter is looking at PS1 at all. There are some variables that can change how noninteractive interpreters are initialized -- do you have ENV set? If so, does unset ENV change it?

(Separately, did you maybe export PS1 in your dotfiles? Don't ever do that -- PS1 should be a non-exported shell variable, not an environment variable. You can test with declare -p PS1 -- the output should start with declare -- PS1=, not declare -x PS1=; the latter would mean you had exported it; don't)

(Separately: sh is not bash; even if sh is a symlink to the bash executable, bash runs in compatibility mode with a great many features turned off when started under the sh name; thus, use the sh tag, not the bash tag, for scripts you run with sh rather than bash; also, note that sh scriptname overrides #!/bin/bash -- if you start something with sh it's treated as a sh script no matter what the shebang says).

What do you think xargs is doing here? Without seeing the contents of the dealer file, we can't help.

@glennjackman The comment says xargs is trimming spaces. xargs with no command argument is equivalent to xargs echo. It's equivalent to dealer=$(echo $dealer) except that wildcards won't be expanded in $dealer.
